# Why label is not showing over the top level window?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, label, toplevel

I'm trying to make a small project on python. I'm new to python.

I need some help to show some text with label widget over top level window that is shown over my main window(root), but i don't know why that text is not appearing within top level window.

Thank you in advance:)

Here's the function:

```
def read_all_csv():
    if entry1.get() == '':
        top = Toplevel(bg='orange')
        x_position = 330
        y_position = 486
        top.geometry(f"340x140+{x_position}+{y_position}")
        l1 = Label(top, text="Please fullfill the area", bg="green", fg="white", height=50, width=50)
        l1.place(x = 335, y = 490)
```

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Are you certain that `read_all_csv` is being called? Have you verified that `entry1.get()` is returning an empty string? Please provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: The size of the toplevel window is 340x140, but you put the label at (335, 490) which is out of the viewable area of the toplevel window.

Comment: @BryanOakley read_all_csv function is being called within a button, yes entry1.get() is returning an empty string so i created my top level window in order to show a warning message but can't fullfill this toplevel window with labels or textboxes or buttons. Top level window is shown but can't show widgets within its window.             Don't know why :(

Comment: @acw1668 toplevel is at 330x486 location so i put label at 335x490 within this window. Maybe is not right but even when i maximize top level window nothing is shown. I tried labels, text boxes, buttons but couldn't put those widgets inside top level window.

Comment: @John No, your code `top.geometry(f"340x140+{x_position}+{y_position}")` makes the size of the toplevel 340x140.  Also I can see the label when I maximize the toplevel.

Answer (score 0):

You are making the window 340x140 pixels wide/tall. The label is being placed at the position 335x490, *relative to the top-left corner of the window*. Therefore, the label is invisible. You can easily verify that fact by manually resizing the window.

If you adjust the coordinates to 0, 0, then the widget will be visible. Personally, I recommend using `pack` in this case since that will guarantee that the full label is visible. It will also automatically make the top-level just big enough to fit its contents.

Comment: No, from the line `top.geometry(f"340x140+{x_position}+{y_position}")` the toplevel is 340x140 wide/tall and put at screen position (330, 486).